# Testing Dynamic Pages using Google Website Optimizer

Tags: javascript, testing, dynamic, quotes, ab-testing

Assume I have a site which shows information regarding restaurants. All the urls are named as /restaurants/some-dynamic-restaurant-name/ eg.../restaurants/somename**1**/, /restaurants/somename**2**/ etc... How can I A/B test or Multivariate test using GWO, all the restaurant pages in one single experiment?

Update: I have created a question in google website optimizer forums, and this is the reply I got: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/websiteoptimizer/thread?tid=5c6ef8fab27cf719&hl=en&fid=5c6ef8fab27cf719000468877f441f7b

Update:Following http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61201, I have taken a sample url www.mysite.com/restaurants/dynamic_restaurant_name_here/. I have a h1-header in that page which displays the Restaurant Name. I included that as a section, following GWO rules. And I created the variations of that using h2,h3. So it is supposed to show h2 header or h3  header for different users for the same restaurant.

Instead, for every other restaurant page, it was showing the same(or only one) restaurant name, because all it knows is that only. But the link which you gave assures me that I can test a similar scenario(check the first few lines of the GWO link content), but that didn't happen. So for each dynamic restaurant page, I want to check different headers. Is that possible?What should I do?

Update:I posted an answer to my own question. But is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

To your first question, no, query parameters are not stripped off.   In fact, the params of the original page are merged with the params of the alternative URL before the redirection to the alternative URL.

To your second question, please see:

```
http://www.gwotricks.com/2009/02/advanced-ab-experiments.html
```

Which shows you how you can gain control over the URL to which visitors are redirected.  This will allow you to test all the restaurant pages.  Essentially, you create a multivariate experiment, hook the redirection and construct the appropriate URL to which the visitor is redirected.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this:http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61201
And I got what I wanted. But then I started working with the same approach in a high scale way, meaning, by just flipping one variable at GWO end, I wanted to flip the whole template design. ie.. version=1 will load a layout1 and version=2 will a layout 2. So I was retrieving the templates content in javascript.
This is how it will look like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if(version==1){
content_to_be_loaded = "<Two pane layout html content>"
}else{
content_to_be_loaded = "<Three pane layout html content>"
}
</script>
```

This sounds good. But the double quotes used are colliding with the html content's double quotes. So javascript is failing to compute the value of the variable "content_to_be_loaded". I can solve this by standardizing the templates text to use only one kind of quotes. But thats rediculous. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: Got it. I escaped all the loaded contents and un-escaped them again after content is loaded into javascript variable. :D